# Is it possible to sort this SOQL statement in one query?

Tags: apex, soql, query, sort

I have a list of records with name fields that all contain something like 'Name1', 'Name2, ..., 'Name20'. It's also not guaranteed that there will be a complete list of 1-20, i.e. it can be a list of 1-13 at times.

I'm looking to sort these records by that Name field where they'll be listed from 1-20, however I'm having difficulty achieving it in one SOQL query.

```
[SELECT Id, Name FROM MyObject WHERE Name LIKE 'Name%' ORDER BY Name ASC]
```

This query results in an order that looks like 'Name10', 'Name11', 'Name12', 'Name13', 'Name1', 'Name2', ... , 'Name9'.

I can do two SOQL statements to get single digit & double digit values, like so:

```
[SELECT Id, Name FROM MyObject WHERE Name LIKE 'Name_' ORDER BY Name ASC]
[SELECT Id, Name FROM MyObject WHERE Name LIKE 'Name__' ORDER BY Name ASC]
```

But this results in two lists that would then have to be concatenated together, which I was hoping to avoid.

Really I'm just hoping there's some secret sneaky way to accomplish this in one query. Any help with this would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ordering that looks like `[1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 2, 20, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` is called *lexicographic ordering*. When you have a mix of alpha and numeric characters, that's the reasonable approach to take (and how SOQL and many other systems handle it).

If you want *numerical* ordering (`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, ...]`), you'll need to do some additional work *somewhere*.

One approach you could take would be to create a formula field (returning a `Decimal`) to strip out the "Name" portion of the name, leaving you with just the numeric value. You could then `ORDER BY <your formula field>` to achieve the ordering you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You're sorting lexicographically, so that means your data would have to be in the right order--that means renaming your data to Name01-Name20; notice the leading 0 for values less than 10. This would be the appropriate way to get the data into a single query.